# Google Search Console API returning empty values

Tags: php, api, search, console, google-search-console

I've been working with the search console API recently, and last week everything worked fine. Authorising with oauth, getting a list of sites and sending a site/page query returned a complete data set.

However, I test the code today and I can get a site list, but the queries all return empty values.

Is there such a thing as an API downtime, does the authentication expire permanently at any time, or is there something else with the search console I'm not aware of?

The code to build the query and return the data is the following:

```
$webmastersService = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
$searchanalytics = $webmastersService->searchanalytics;
$request = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;

$request->setStartDate('2013-01-01');
$request->setEndDate('2015-01-01');
$request->setDimensions(array("[query]"));

$qsearch = $searchanalytics->query("http://www.example.com", $request); 
$rows = $qsearch->getRows();
```

It just returns a completely empty array...

Comment: Should not this line `$request->setDimensions(array("[query]"));` be without square bracket ? Like this: `$request->setDimensions(array("query"));`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that search console api was down for a couple of days, which is why it returned empty values!